# Docusign - Getting Empty Document on download

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I am integrating Docusign in a laravel project with this package [docusign/esign-client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client). I am trying to download the document from the envelope sent, using following code:

```
 $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(new ApiClient($configuration));
 $tempFile = $envelopeApi->getDocument($config['accountId'], 'combined', $config['envelopeId']);
 file_put_contents('combined.pdf', file_get_contents($tempFile->getPathName()));
  
 $tempFile = $envelopeApi->getDocument($config['accountId'], '1', $config['envelopeId']);
 file_put_contents('sample.pdf', file_get_contents($tempFile->getPathName()));
```

In both the case , the file being saved is of zero bytes, which means empty.

The same issue happens in the example codes as well, which can be checked out [here](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Controllers/Examples/eSignature/EG007EnvelopeGetDoc.php)

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We've opened a JIRA ticket to investigate this further. Can you please reach out through https://support.docusign.com/ with reference to this post for communication regarding it?